# Newsletter attached images does not display it in email client but show as attachment

Tags: html, newsletter

We are creating one newsletter for our client. We are sending images used in newsletter as attachment and giving image path as below:

```
<img src="sample.jpg" />
```

However this work well in outlook and but all other mail client and mobile device like iPad/iPhone does not show images as default instead of this they show images as attachment of mail.

Any guess or solution for this. Why this happening like this and does not show images used in newsletter while loading an email.

Comment: Message source (abridged to just the essentials, please) would be necessary for any sort of analysis, or even guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

This is not best practice for email. You should host the images online:

```
<img src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/sample.jpg" />
```

Alternatively, you can look into embedding the images in base64.